# Uwamp - apache not starting with gui but starts fine manually with httpd.exe

Tags: apache, uwamp

Some thing has happened in the last day with Uwamp not starting up Apache, but when I manually go into the httpd.exe folder and run it from a command line apache starts fine and I can access localhost easily. Any thing come to mind?  I was playing with clipboard apps yesterday but how could they affect Uwamp starting httpd.exe??

After 2 days, still can't find out what's wrong. Developer is not answering this question. Yes, he knows this question exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have had the same problem, but it looks like it could be down to the mscvr1110.dll issue Visual c++ 2012 runtime, you must install the 32 bit version along side with the 64 bit [if you are running a 64bit windows] and I would personally install the 32 bit first [then the 64bit  - if applicable]

the one problem I have noticed is if you are selecting php 7 then it loads httpd.conf rather than the httpd_uwamp.conf, so at the moment I wouldn't select that option.

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Gee, I feel so silly, thanks devouk, that was it! I ran the 64 bit which was already installed but said to fix it, I guess it did and now it works great!