# Apache service not working even though httpd.exe works fine

Tags: windows, apache, windows-services, mod-wsgi

For some reason ever since I installed `mod_wsgi` on Apache 2.4 on Windows 10, the service for starting Apache on the background stopped working and no error is logged.

If I go to the `bin` folder where Apache is installed I can just open a CMD windows and write `httpd` and it starts listening and everything works fine.

I saw [this similar on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810241/uwamp-apache-not-starting-with-gui-but-starts-fine-manually-with-httpd-exe) but I have already installed both x64 and x86 versions of the VC++ 2012 runtime.

If I comment out the line that loads `python36.dll` along with the one that loads `mod_wsgi`, the service starts without any issues.

P.S. I installed Apache from Apache Lounge and I'm not using XAMP, WAMP ...

Comment: The Apache service doesn't run as you, but a separate user. Is Python or mod_wsgi installed into your own account. If so, user Apache starts up as may not have access to the files.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, Python is installed for ALL users in the system.

Comment: Where was mod_wsgi installed though? Into the system Python version, or a virtual environment?

Comment: I installed it with `pip install mod_wsgi` and not using a virtual environment.

Comment: There must be some error in the Apache error log, or service log. What do you see? What were the actual lines you added to the Apache configuration file. There has been instances that what ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` generated was wrong. This was not with Python 3.6 though, which would expect to work okay.

Comment: Hang, on. Why do you have VC++ 2012. That looks to be wrong compiler for Python 3.6. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, that's just the redistributable edition not the SDK, I compiled the module using Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools

Comment: So what actual error messages are in logs? And the config?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Errors are not logged. Not in Apache logs folder and not even in event viewer. It just doesn't start.